# Mysterious characters in output with utf8_encode and utf8_decode

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, html-entities

i want to print many strings of countries that i retrieve from my database but i have a mysterious caracter every time when i use :

```
utf8_encode($string); the out put is  (AlgÃ©rie ,  ArmÃ©nie ,AzerbaÃ¯djan ,BiÃ©lorussie )
utf8_decode($string); -> (Algérie , Arménie , Azerba?djan , Bi?lorussie )
htmlentities($string); -> (AlgÃ?Â©rie , ArmÃ?Â©nie ,AzerbaÃ¯djan, ... )
```

i have tried to put in the header :

```
header ("Content-Type:text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"); ->ArmÃ©nie , Azerbaïdjan
```

and

```
header ("Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8");  -> Azerba�djan
```

i have checked in the config of my database and i found

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

Any idea ?

Comment: what does it put out without all this encoding stuff?

Comment: AlgÃ©rie , ArmÃ©nie , Azerbaïdjan

Answer (score 0):

This can sometimes happen when you're using something like utf8_decode on a string that is already decoded, or encoding on something that's already UTF8. If that's what you're doing, try not encoding/decoding the string to start with, and then see what the output is.

I had this problem in CodeIgniter myself, decoding something that was already decoded made the characters go wonky.

If you're pulling data from a database, check the collation of the tables/fields in there too.